# VBA Code for dynamic Range to update Stock Chart

Tags: vba, dynamic, range, stock, excel-charts

I am VBA Learner and working with Stock OHLC Chart, looking forward with experts for my problem.
Sheet 2: Has data in Column A to E (Column has header as Date, Open, High, low and Close).
Sheet 1: having Chart and only want to modify range.
Range should be 60 Row up from Last Row and 15 Row below of Data set
I am trying with code

```
Dim FCl As Range

Dim LCl As Range

FCl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select - 60

LCl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range("A1").End(xlDown).Select + 15
```

Experts please guide me.

Comment: What exactly is the problem. Is it you are unsuccessful in setting your ranges?

Comment: Yes, unsuccessful in setting ranges for stock chart

Comment: Is the range supposed to be a single cell or from the top of the sheet etc? Your question and code are not clear what exactly your range is supposed to be.

Comment: Can I share you sheet? Could you please share your e mail id.

Comment: It would be better if you edited your question to include clearer information of your issue. 
FYI you need the `Set` statement for a `Range` object, i.e. `Set FC1 = ThisWorkbook...`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with following code...

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Dim ws2 As Worksheet

Set ws2 ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Dim LastRow As Long

LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim StartRange As Long

StartRange = LastRow - 59

Dim EndRange As Long

EndRange = LastRow + 15
```

Thanks all